# Regex: Running a command with regex path in terminal

Tags: regex, cucumber, regex-lookarounds

I have a regex for all my file paths that I want to access

```
^features\/US\/(?!deal_string\/)[a-m].*$
```

but when I give this regex to a command it throws an error which says no such file path exists.
How can I make it work? I'm trying to run cucumber tests for selected features only.

```
script/cucumber filepath_regex
```

Basically, I want all files with path

```
features/US/[a-m]*
```

except

```
features/US/deal_opertaions/*
```

to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using tags for this instead of trying to use a regex expression.

In your feature file, you can set a tag like @dont_run, or whatever you want to call it in the feature file of

```
features/US/deal_opertaions/*
```

**More information on tags can be found [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags).**

Then, in the cmd window you could do something like

```
cucumber features/US --tags ~@dont_run
```

That should run all features in the US file that are NOT tagged with @dont_run.

Comment: simple and clean solution, Thanks.